# How do I use DarkIcons.dll in a Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, icons, resource-files, appbar

Building my first Windows Phone 8 app and I am bringing in a few icons to use in the appbar. As I am picking the icons in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\Dark` I see that there is a file called `DarkIcons.dll`.

Can I use this dll as a resource file and then bind to icons in it?

If so how does that binding work? What does the binding look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AppBar icons, you should use the white "dark" icons in that folder or from other resources like [modernuiicons](http://modernuiicons.com/). Add these to your project as a resource and set the icon to be this image. If your application is used on a device that has a light theme, the phone will turn the icons black for you. No need for you to do anything!

Comment: I have added the icons to the project using the copy and paste way. Thanks for the info on the dark vs. light theme and the link to more icons.

Comment: You're welcome, and to further answer your question, that dll is not for application use.

Answer (score 0):

Well. You need not to do anything with .dll file for App Bar icons. You need not to worry about that dll file. Because while you create the new project, all dll files will be initiated. This dll is the primary file. Windows sdk will care about more than you

Simply copy and paste the desired icons from "dark" folder in the solution explorer.

Simply call that image and you can use all icons like this.

If your phone theme was dark, then the colors of icons will be light and vice versa.

Hope this could be useful to you. All the best.

Comment: Picking the icons and adding them individually into my app is exactly what I have done. But that really doesn't answer the question. Can I use the dll as a resource instead? If so how?

Comment: You need not to worry about that `dll` file. Because while you create the new project, all dll files will be initiated. This dll is the primary file. Windows sdk will care about more than you. :-)